# r studio: simulate my code 1000 times and pick the things which p value<0.05

Tags: r, simulation

Here is my original code:

```
x = rbinom(1000,1,0.5)
z = log(1.3)*x       
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z)) 
y = rbinom(1000,1,pr)     
k=glm(y~x,family="binomial")$coef
t=exp(k)
```

How can I simulate it 1000 times and pick the one with a p-value<0.05?

Comment: It seems redundant to first log-transform `z=log(1.3)*x` and then reverse back `t=exp(k)`. While we could `z=1.3*x` and compare with the `coef` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect application for the tidyverse and it's list columns. Please see explanation in the inline comments.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

# create a tibble with an id column for each simulation and x wrapped in list()
sim <- tibble(id = 1:1000,
               x = list(rbinom(1000,1,0.5))) %>% 
# to generate z, pr, y, k use map and map2 from the purrr package to loop over the list column x
# `~ ... ` is similar to `function(.x) {...}`
# `.x` represents the variable you are using map on
          mutate(z  = map(x, ~ log(1.3) * .x), 
                 pr = map(z, ~ 1 / (1 + exp(-.x))),
                 y  = map(pr, ~ rbinom(1000, 1, .x)),
                 k  = map2(x, y, ~ glm(.y ~ .x, family="binomial")),
# use broom::tidy to get the model summary in form of a tibble
                 sum = map(k, broom::tidy)) %>% 
# select id and sum and unnest the tibbles
  select(id, sum) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(sum)) %>% 
# drop the intercepts and every .x with a p < 0.05
  filter(term !="(Intercept)",
         p.value < 0.05)

sim  
#> # A tibble: 545 x 6
#>       id term  estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>    <int> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1     3 .x       0.301     0.127      2.37 0.0176  
#>  2     7 .x       0.263     0.127      2.06 0.0392  
#>  3     8 .x       0.293     0.127      2.31 0.0211  
#>  4    11 .x       0.377     0.128      2.96 0.00312 
#>  5    12 .x       0.265     0.127      2.08 0.0373  
#>  6    13 .x       0.366     0.127      2.88 0.00403 
#>  7    14 .x       0.461     0.128      3.61 0.000305
#>  8    17 .x       0.274     0.127      2.16 0.0309  
#>  9    18 .x       0.394     0.127      3.09 0.00200 
#> 10    19 .x       0.371     0.127      2.92 0.00354 
#> # … with 535 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: New question here: now I extract all the value which p<0.05, now I using the code "hist(OR,main=NULL,freq=T,breaks=10)" to make a histogram for the odds ratio. The new things I want to do is make another histogram(like without any condition for p-value) overlapping the original one, then I could compare the histogram with the different p-value in one plot, which code can work like that?

Comment: @misayali Have you forgot to accept this as an answer? To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: @RyanSYKwan I just did it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RyanSYKwan Still a little question here: I use broom::tidy to get the model summary in form of a tibble, but if I want to print out the original matrix which creates in tibble function(like only include x and y), what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I won't do this for you, but these are the steps you'll probably want to go through:

1. Write your code as a function that returns the value you're interested in (presumably t)
2. Use something like `replicate` to run this function many times and record all the answers
3. Use something like `quantile` to extract the percentile you're interested in